# Read Excel file using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am writing a c# program to read excel file using OpenXML.
I have a list of words added in a column in the excel file in a column.I want to read them and add to an array list.
I am using the below code

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePatah + "\\" + fileName, false))
 {
       WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
       WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
       SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

       ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
       foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
       {
          foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
          {
             data.Add(c.CellValue.Text);
          }
       }
 }
```

What I am seing is 1,2,3,4 etc with this while I am expecting the words to list.
What should I need to do to get the words ?

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5115257/465053).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual strings are stored in the [SharedStringTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278314.aspx). What you are getting are only the references to the elements in that string table.

Here's your sample modified to retrieve the values from the string table:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePatah + "\\" + fileName, false))
{
   WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
   WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
   SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

   ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
   foreach (Row r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
   {
      foreach (Cell c in r.Elements<Cell>())
      {
        if (c.DataType != null && c.DataType == CellValues.SharedString)
        {
            var stringId = Convert.ToInt32(c.InnerText); // Do some error checking here
            data.Add(workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(stringId).InnerText);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Please note that this is just a crude example. For a little more complete examples you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115257/open-xml-excel-read-cell-value).

Also, depending on what you need, you might find using a library such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) much easier (you can read and write directly to cells without worrying about the actual document format) than OpenXML SDK.