# read cell value preserve precision

Tags: c#, excel

I am Reading Excel using C# with
    string cellvalue= worksheet.Cells[2, 2].Text;
and the exact value in that cell is 0.0833333333333333 but the above code could only read value 0.083333333 which is the visible value in the excel sheet as well. this is cause of data loss/precision loss. how should i read the value of excel cell to get the 16 digit precision.

Comment: i would suggest use openxml for your requirement .. some solutions with openxml usages are as follows ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115257/open-xml-excel-read-cell-value

Comment: Did you try reading `Value` instead of `Text` ?

Comment: worksheet.Cells[2, 2].Value is not availabe :( . Any other option without using third party.

Comment: use .Value2 see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Charles, Value2 worked for me. Initially i was not able to find value2 on Cell. Then I used 
    object rangeObject = sheet.Cells[row, column];
    Range range = (Range)rangeObject;
    string cellValue;
    cellValue = rangeValue != null ? rangeValue.ToString() : 0.ToString()