# Retrieving DataTable from Memory Stream.

Tags: c#, serialization, datatable, deserialization, memorystream

I have a data table that is formatted from an array of Column Names, I.e.

```
        DataTable ThisTable = new DataTable();

        for (int i = 0; i <= col.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                ThisTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col[i].ToString(), typeof(string)));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Uploader  Error"+e.ToString());
                return null; 
            }
        }
```

i then use a `BinaryFormatter` object to Serialize/Deserialize a memory stream so that I can read the data from the stream into a table. Essentially users will be uploading an excel sheet that will be read into a database. Although I realize that it is possible, **I DO NOT want to write the sheet to disk then read it in**.

However when I go to retrieve the datatable from the `Deserialize()` call, I dont get an error, however I get an empty DataSet.

Mem would be my memory stream object.

```
        BinaryFormatter bformat = new BinaryFormatter();
        bformat.Serialize(Mem, ThisTable);
        Mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] bt = Mem.ToArray();


        Stream s = new MemoryStream(bt);
        Mem.Position = 0;            
        s.Position = 0; 
        ThisTable = (DataTable)bformat.Deserialize(Mem); 
        DS.Tables.Add(ThisTable);

        return DS;
```

Comment: I don't think that's the way to go... there are much easier ways to do what you're talking about.

Comment: well what would that be?

Comment: When you say that you get an empty DataSet, do you mean DataSet.Tables == null? Or DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0?

Comment: I meant that I have a data table from the Deserialize() call, but no rows.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the OpenXml SDK to read the Excel file into the DataTable.

Take a look at the answer from M_R_H for an example:

[From Excel to DataTable in C# with Open XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321082/from-excel-to-datatable-in-c-with-open-xml)

You can also look at the answer from amurra here for another example:

[reading Excel Open XML is ignoring blank cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837981/reading-excel-open-xml-is-ignoring-blank-cells)

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is an error in the sample code you posted, you aren't populating the DataTable with any data, you are just creating columns.  You can add rows to the DataTable via `DataTable.Rows.Add()`:

```
foreach(var o in myDataSource)
{
    ThisTable.Rows.Add(o.Prop1, o.Prop2, etc);
}
```

Comment: I am creating a memorystream object with the file that is uploaded from a FileUpload control. the MemoryStream "should" contain all the data

Comment: @Kwalke001 - The call to `bformat.Serialize(Mem, ThisTable)` is serializing the `ThisTable` object to your stream.  If `ThisTable` contains no data at this point, it will contain no data when it is deserialized.