# Skip first cell & last cell - From Excel to DataTable in C# with Open XML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have implemented this code as mentioned here :

[From Excel to DataTable in C# with Open XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321082/from-excel-to-datatable-in-c-sharp-with-open-xml)

My excel is like this : [image]

So now the code which I wrote does not work as I am unable to skip the first row with unwanted text.

I need to skip the first row & last row, extracting data only from the columns & rows

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to read an Excel file is to use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library.

You could then take a look at the following examples to import your worksheet into datatables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396604/excel-to-datatable-using-epplus-excel-locked-for-editing) or [here](https://logicalcafe.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/reading-an-excel-2007-xlsx-into-a-datatable-without-installing-offic/).

Hope this helps !