# OpenXML - Not reading a blank Cell from a row C#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an .xlsx file with 3 columns SrNumber,Name,Active in A,B and C columns respectively.

I am reading the content of this file in a DataTable using the source code given in the answer of following question

[From Excel to DataTable in C# with Open XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321082/from-excel-to-datatable-in-c-sharp-with-open-xml)

I have also did the modificaitons suggested by Sourabh

It works fine when my content is as follows

```
    A           B       C
1   SrNumber    Name    Active
2   1           test1   Yes
3   2           test2   Yes
4   3           test3   Yes
5   4           test4   Yes
```

Now when I am trying to add a row at 6th position I am entering the data only in B6 and C6 cells. **I have not touched A6 Cell.**

After running that code I am getting my DataTable filled as follows

[image]

You can see that value entered in B6 coming in first column and value entered in C6 coming in second column.
Also `row.Descendants<Cell>()` returning only 2 cells for the newly entered row.

Please let me know if any modifications to be done in the source code.

Comment: Please post the code you are actually using. Then your question would be self contained.

Comment: The same code of answer of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321082/from-excel-to-datatable-in-c-sharp-with-open-xml having 54 upvotes. With modifications suggested by user Sourabh(8 Upvotes)..

Comment: I believe that code is buggy for the reasons I list in my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875815/get-the-column-index-of-a-cell-in-excel-using-openxml-c-sharp/31035990#31035990). If I find time I'll add an answer either to this or your linked question.

Comment: The example code you link to is old. I suggest you rather use ClosedXml NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/
It has a much better api for interacting with Excel documents, and does not require installation of Office. I have used it a lot, and I recommend it.

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3837981/465053).

Answer (score 2):

```
//Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
            IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);

            //Create a new DataTable.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
            bool firstRow = true;
            foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
            {
                //Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                if (firstRow)
                {
                    foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    firstRow = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Add rows to DataTable.
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 0;
                    //for (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                    for (int j=1;j<= dt.Columns.Count;j++)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cell(j).Value.ToString()))
                            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = "";
                        else
                            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = row.Cell(j).Value.ToString();
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should do the trick for you. `CellReferenceToIndex` is of real importance which does the calculation of actual cell index when we encounter empty cells:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

public static DataTable ReadAsDataTable(string fileName)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
        string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
        Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
        SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
        IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();

        foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(0))
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell));
        }

        foreach (Row row in rows)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Descendants<Cell>().Count(); i++)
            {
                 Cell cell = row.Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(i);
                 int actualCellIndex = CellReferenceToIndex(cell);
                 dataRow[actualCellIndex] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell);
            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

    }
    dataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(0);

    return dataTable;
}

private static string GetCellValue(SpreadsheetDocument document, Cell cell)
{
    SharedStringTablePart stringTablePart = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
    string value = cell.CellValue.InnerXml;

    if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
    {
        return stringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements[Int32.Parse(value)].InnerText;
    }
    else
    {
        return value;
    }
}

private static int CellReferenceToIndex(Cell cell)
{
    int index = 0;
    string reference = cell.CellReference.ToString().ToUpper();
    foreach (char ch in reference)
    {
        if (Char.IsLetter(ch))
        {
            int value = (int)ch - (int)'A';
            index = (index == 0) ? value : ((index + 1) * 26) + value;
        }
        else
            return index;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Good solution. However, it does not work for cells after "Z". When it encounters cell "AA" the value is set to 0

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still unable to do this, simply use CloseXML.Excel with the code below:

```
    public DataTable ImportTable(DataTable dt, string FileName)
    {
        //Open excel file
        Statics.currentProgressValue = 0;
        Statics.maxProgressValue = 100;
        try
        {
            bool fileExist = File.Exists(FileName);
            if (fileExist)
            {
                using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(FileName))
                {
                    IXLWorksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);

                    var rowCount = workSheet.RangeUsed().RowCount();
                    if (rowCount > 0)
                    {
                        //return dt;
                        var colCount = workSheet.Row(1).CellsUsed().Count();
                        if (dt.Columns.Count < colCount)
                            throw new Exception($"Expects at least {dt.Columns.Count} columns.");

                        //Loop through the Worksheet rows.
                        Statics.maxProgressValue = rowCount;
                        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
                        {
                            Statics.currentProgressValue += 1;
                            dt.Rows.Add();
                            for (int j = 2; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                            {
                                var cell = (workSheet.Rows().ElementAt(i).Cell(j));
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString()))
                                    dt.Rows[i - 1][j] = cell.Value.ToString().Trim();
                                else
                                    dt.Rows[i - 1][j] = "";
                            }
                            if (Statics.cancelProgress == true)
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error exporting data." +
                Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```