# Open XML Spreadsheet read table

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an excel spreadsheet that I need to be able to import. This spreadsheet has many named tables on it within 1 sheet that have a few different schemas as well as some other random data throughout the sheet. I need to be able to read the data within each individual table.

I have figured out how to get a list of the the tables that are available and how to read their column headers, but I am not sure how I get access to the data.

The following is a sample of the code that I have for reading the headers. I really don't need this information (as I will be putting these into a model and already know the order of the columns), it does show kind of what I am working with.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Data;

...

public static DataTable GetNamedDataTable(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument, string cellRange, string DataTableName)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    Workbook woorkbook = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook;
    //Sheet 
    var bustedCellRange = BustCellRange(cellRange);
    Sheet sheet = woorkbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == bustedCellRange["sheetName"]).FirstOrDefault();
    SharedStringTable sharedStringTable = woorkbook.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
    List<SharedStringItem> allSharedStringItems= sharedStringTable.Descendants<SharedStringItem>().ToList();
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);

    TableDefinitionPart tableDefinitionPart = worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Table.Name == DataTableName);
    QueryTablePart queryTablePart = tableDefinitionPart.QueryTableParts.FirstOrDefault();
    Table excelTable = tableDefinitionPart.Table;
    int columnCounter = 0;
    foreach(TableColumn column in excelTable.TableColumns)
    {
        DataColumn dataColumn = dataTable.Columns.Add(column.Name);
        dataColumn.SetOrdinal(columnCounter);
        columnCounter++;
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321082/from-excel-to-datatable-in-c-sharp-with-open-xml) is getting a bit old, but I think the content is still relevant for you here.

Comment: @JacobH the problem with that is that it is reading the entire sheet, what I have is 1 sheet with many tables and a few random pieces of data throughout. I will update the question to be a little more explicit.

Comment: Is the data in the same range/table of the worksheet with the headers? Like, is the data already in `excelTable`? If so, just iterate through the `rows` and add them as new datarows to the `dataTable`.

Comment: @JacobH, unless I am missing something the DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Table object doesn't have a rows collection. Do you know how I can access this, as this would be a perfect solution.

Comment: Can you use the sheetdata class by passing the table to it's constructor? (I actually don't know, I have only used the Excel XML methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this. See below if you are having the same issue, note that I do plan to clean this up quite a bit on my own project, but this should get you going.

```cs
public static DataTable GetNamedDataTable(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument, string DataTableName)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    Workbook woorkbook = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook;
    Sheet sheet = woorkbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == "SheetName").FirstOrDefault();
    SharedStringTable sharedStringTable = woorkbook.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
    List<SharedStringItem> allSharedStringItems= sharedStringTable.Descendants<SharedStringItem>().ToList();
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id);
    TableDefinitionPart tableDefinitionPart = worksheetPart.TableDefinitionParts.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Table.Name == DataTableName);
    QueryTablePart queryTablePart = tableDefinitionPart.QueryTableParts.FirstOrDefault();
    Table excelTable = tableDefinitionPart.Table;
    int columnCounter = 0;
    foreach(TableColumn column in excelTable.TableColumns)
    {
       DataColumn dataColumn = dataTable.Columns.Add(column.Name);
       dataColumn.SetOrdinal(columnCounter);
       columnCounter++;
    }

    var newCellRange = excelTable.Reference;
    var startCell = newCellRange.Value.Split(':')[0];
    var endCell = newCellRange.Value.Split(':')[1];

    uint firstRowNum = GetRowIndex(startCell);
    uint lastRowNum = GetRowIndex(endCell);
    string firstColumn = GetColumnName(startCell);
    string lastColumn = GetColumnName(endCell);

    var columnIndex = 0;
    foreach (Row row in worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex.Value > firstRowNum && r.RowIndex.Value <= lastRowNum))
    {
        var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        foreach (Cell cell in row)
        {                
            string columnName = GetColumnName(cell.CellReference.Value);
            if (CompareColumn(columnName, firstColumn) >= 0 && CompareColumn(columnName, lastColumn) <= 0)
            {
                if (cell.CellValue != null)
                {
                    dataRow[columnIndex] = cell.CellValue.Text;
                }
                columnIndex++;
            }
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        columnIndex = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    return dataTable;
}

private static uint GetRowIndex(string cellName)
{
    // Create a regular expression to match the row index portion the cell name.
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
    Match match = regex.Match(cellName);
    return uint.Parse(match.Value);
}

// Given a cell name, parses the specified cell to get the column name.
private static string GetColumnName(string cellName)
{
    // Create a regular expression to match the column name portion of the cell name.
    Regex regex = new Regex("[A-Za-z]+");
    Match match = regex.Match(cellName);
    return match.Value;
}

// Given two columns, compares the columns.
private static int CompareColumn(string column1, string column2)
{
    if (column1.Length > column2.Length)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (column1.Length < column2.Length)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return string.Compare(column1, column2, true);
    }
}
```

CREDIT for this answer must go to the following site as it is what lead me to be able to figure this out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-a-range-of-cells-in-a-spreadsheet-document

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to add that you need `allSharedStringItems` to convert values of text cell into strings