# How to import an excel file with hundreds of sheets to a database to use in C# project?

Tags: c#, excel

I'm pretty new to C# and programming.
I have an excel file with more than 100 sheets.
In each sheet I have more than 200 lines with data (4 columns on each line).
I need to use data from each sheet in a C# project.
Do I need to use a database to upload the data from sheets? If yes, what database to use and how can I put values from Excel to this database to use them after in C# more easily?
I read Google to find how can I do this but I found a lot of things and I don't understand.
Thank you!

Comment: I would use BulkCopy to copy the sheets to a database.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible solutions:

1. Use an library to access excel. There are several alternatives, but [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) seem to be one of the most downloaded one.
2. [Use ADO.Net to access the excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp). This treats the excel file as a database, and might be a bit difficult to use unless you are comfortable with SQL.
3. [Use excel interop library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp). This will require that excel is installed on the machine that is used.

Comment: I do not recommend to use Excel Interop. 

MS Office Interop is slow and even Microsoft does not recommend Interop usage on server side. For more details see what Microsoft stated on [why not to use OLE Automation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a database. You can use [OpenXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) to import your data in C#.

You may find plenty of examples about how to import data with OpenXML, this is only one of them:
[From Excel to DataTable in C# with Open XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321082/from-excel-to-datatable-in-c-sharp-with-open-xml)

There are also other open source Excel libraries that you can use. OpenXML is from Microsoft and it was built specially for handling Excel files.